# Clonar repositorios git a granel

Tags: git, script, clone

¿Hay algún script que me permita clonar más de 100 repositorios git al mismo tiempo? Por Ejemplo:

```
https://github.com/Geovation/wifispy/
https://github.com/wlanslovenija/wireless-info
https://github.com/stef/wireless-radar/
https://github.com/gauravpatwardhan/Wireless-Sniffer

https://github.com/jeffThompson/MappingWirelessNetworks
https://github.com/pan0pt1c0n/WAPMap
https://github.com/0x90/warcarrier
https://github.com/cyberpython/WifiScanAndMap/
https://github.com/travisgoodspeed/80211scrambler
....
```

Comment: ¿En qué sistema operativo quieres hacerlo? ¿Quieres clonarlos uno tras otro o en paralelo todos a la vez? Si es en paralelo, ¿con un límite de, por ejemplo, 5 simultáneos?

Comment: Cody, hay en Stack Overflow, en inglés, cómo realizarlo. De hecho, mi respuesta está fundamentada en la página en inglés.

Comment: Lo siento. Estoy usando el sistema operativo Macintosh y quiero clonarlos uno por uno, pero con un script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cody. Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español.
Tu pregunta se puede resolver de forma sencilla sabiendo cómo clonar un único repositorio:

Según en la web de Altassian: https://es.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/setting-up-a-repository/git-clone [image]

Es tan fácil como `git clone ssh://john@example.com/path/to/my-project.git`

Bien, para hacerlo sobre 100 repositorios, y además en un script, necesitaríamos saber algo más acerca del script.
Las preguntas básicas que se me vienen a la cabeza son:

- ¿Lo quieres en un bash (para linux), batch (para windows)?
- ¿Acaso lo quieres para integrar dentro de un lenguaje de scripts tipo javascript o python, por ejemplo?

En Stack Overflow, en inglés, ofrecen más información sobre cómo realizarlo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900294/clone-multiple-git-repositories-in-one-local-directory[image]

Te extraigo uno de los scripts utilizados:

> Esto es un ejemplo de un script de bash para Linux. Primero, hay que poner en un archivo todos los repositorios a clonar. Con cat, podrás ver todos tus repositorios en ese archivo. Ten en cuenta que tendrás que hacerlo en una carpeta limpia, porque se copiarán todos tus repositorios en dicha carpeta.

```
$ cat clone
https://github.com/igorsobreira/igorsobreira.com https://github.com/ella/ella https://github.com/divio/django-cms/ https://github.com/palewire/palewire.com https://github.com/jabapyth/jfcom https://github.com/humanfromearth/snippify https://github.com/scaphilo/koalixcrm https://github.com/jlev/Boycott-Toolkit https://github.com/jbalogh/zamboni/ https://github.com/ASKBOT/askbot-devel https://github.com/emesik/djiki https://github.com/vicalloy/LBForum https://github.com/agiliq/agiliq https://github.com/bartTC/dpaste.de https://github.com/bartTC/django-paste https://github.com/bartTC/dpaste_de/ https://github.com/fotochest/fotochest https://esp.mit.edu/git/esp-project.git https://github.com/titan2x/bashoneliners.git
```

> En segundo lugar, ejecutas el siguiente comando

```
$ for f in `cat clone`; do `git clone $f`; done
```

> Y comenzará la clonación de todos y cada uno de los repositorios a la carpeta que tienes designada.

---

No es la única manera, hay muchas más. En la página de SO en inglés te detallan más opciones.

Allí comentan que puedes tener un problema con las credenciales, que te las repetirá en sucesivas ocasiones. Así que, si tuvieses ese problema, tendrías que repetir tu nombre de usuario y contraseña, si el repositorio así lo requiere.